# ValueError: Cell is empty

Tags: pyspark

Below code is not working :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

smallOrig = [{'node': 'A'}]

schema = StructType([StructField("node", StringType(), True)])

my_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(smallOrig, schema)
my_sdf.show()
```

I'm getting this error : `ValueError: Cell is empty`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

smallOrig = [{'node': 'A'}]

rdd = sc.parallelize(smallOrig)

schema = StructType([StructField("node", StringType(), True)])

my_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) 

my_sdf.show()
```

**Output** -

```
+----+
|node|
+----+
|   A|
+----+
```